# Rails put validation in a module mixin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, models

Some validations are repetitive in my models:

```
validates :name, :length => { :minimum => 2 }, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
validates :name_seo, :length => { :minimum => 2 }, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

How would I put that in a mixin? I get this error if I just put 'em in a mixin

```
app/models/validations.rb:5: undefined method `validates' for Validations:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
module Validations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validates :name, :length => { :minimum => 2 }, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
    validates :name_seo, :length => { :minimum => 2 }, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  end
end
```

The `validates` macro must be evaluated in the context of the includer, not of the module (like you probably were doing).

Comment: Is there a any way to do this in rails 2

Comment: Just an aside, I would probably name it `SeoValidatable` and keep it within that domain.

Answer (score 29):

Your module should look something like this:

```
module CommonValidations
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validates :name, :length => { :minimum => 2 }, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
    validates :name_seo, :length => { :minimum => 2 }, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  end
end
```

Then in your model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include CommonValidations

  ...
end
```

I'm using [ActiveSupport::Concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) here to make the code a little clearer.

Comment: Is it possible to test it in Rails 2? For example in the Rails 3 you can use ActiveModel for creating a class Test ; end and include what we need. and then write specs for this module. But what about Rails 2 version is it possible?