# What is the most DRY way to implement multiple table inheritance in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a few tables in my application that share most columns. I wrote all validations in one model and tried to make all other models inherit from this one but got an `ActiveRecord::SublassNotFound` error.

Here is the code for my models:

#### `hospital.rb`

```rb
class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :cnes, presence: true, numericality: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 80 }
  validates :address, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :neighborhood, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
  validates :phone, presence: true, length: { in: 10..25 }
  validates :latitude, :longitude, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }
  validates :type, presence: true
```

#### `pharmacy.rb`

```rb
class Pharmacy < Hospital
  self.table_name = 'pharmacies' 
end
```

Both tables have the exact same columns and I choose to use MTI to give my database more scalability, since both pharmacy and hospital will also have STI to multiple models.

This is the error I'm getting:

```
ActiveRecord::SubclassNotFound:
  Invalid single-table inheritance type: Hospital is not a subclass of Pharmacy
```

I would like to reuse the validations and some methods I intend to implement for both models.

Comment: If you want to re-use the same code (validations) in both models why don't you just use a mixin or concern? Regarding multi-table inheritance, I would argue that Ruby on Rails prefers single table inheritance and fighting against Rails conventions is almost never a good idea. A `type` column has a very special meaning when working with classes inherit from another ActiveRecord class. That might be the reason for our issues.

Comment: In the case you showed me in the link, I would put the module in the `concern` folder, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is an abstract class:

```
class Hospital < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  # validations...
end
```

Then remove the table names from your subclasses.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a separate table, you should not be using a different model as subclass. In this case you just want to inherit from `ActiveRecord::Base`. If you want to share the validations, you could put them in a module and require it in both models.

Of course you could also move to real STI, but in that case you would need to add a `type` column to the single table. In that case you are able to inherit from `Hospital`, but it would be even better to inherit from `Institute` and let `Hospital` also inherit from that Base class.

```
class Institute < ActiveRecord::Base
  # put your validations here
end

class Hospital < Institute
end

class Pharmacy < Institute 
end
```

Edit: if you like to use MTI... see this answer for how to set-up validation Mixins: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11372578/891359